# Pandas xs slow for DataFrame.apply

Tags: python, indexing, pandas

I have a DataFrame with multi-index ['timestamp', 'symbol'] that contains timeseries data.  I merging this data with other samples and my apply function that uses asof is similar to:

```
df.apply(lambda x: df2.xs(x['symbol'], level='symbol').index.asof(x['timestamp'])), axis=1)
```

I think the actual xs to filter on symbol is what is causing it to be so slow, so I am instead creating a dict of 'symbol' -> df where the values are already filtered so I can just call index.asof directly.  Am I approaching this the wrong way?

Example:

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("ts,symbol,bid,ask\n2014-03-03T09:30:00,A,54.00,55.00\n2014-03-03T09:30:05,B,34.00,35.00"), parse_dates='ts', index_col=['ts', 'symbol'])
df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO("ts,eventId,symbol\n2014-03-03T09:32:00,1,A\n2014-03-03T09:33:05,2,B"), parse_dates='ts', index_col=['ts', 'symbol'])

# find ts to join with and use xs so we can use indexof
df2['event_ts'] = df2.apply(lambda x: df.xs(x['symbol'], level='symbol').index.asof(x['ts'])), axis=1)
# merge in fields 
df2 = pd.merge(df2, df, left_on=['event_ts', 'symbol'], right_index=True)
```

Comment: yes, use merge and vectorized operations instead. You are doing an O(n2) operations in python space here searching each the entire rowset each time.

Comment: @Jeff Sorry, I don't follow.  Can you provide an example?

Comment: you would have to provide an example of your input/output and code

Comment: @Jeff I added an example, I hope it's clear.  Basically I'm finding the appropriate timestamp and assigning that col first to the destination table, then doing a merge on that.  Perhaps there is a better way?

Comment: not sure what you are going for here. looks like you might simply want to resample on both intervals to common times then join, seems easier.

Comment: @Jeff These aren't intervals they are event timestamps and since they don't align, I need to use indexof to find the "closest" match.

Comment: try subtracting then finding the idxmin